# Roots of the incomplete gamma function

Tags: special-functions, roots, gamma-function

Is there any way that one can describe all the roots of the incomplete gamma function $\Gamma(n,z)$, for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, analytically?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

(This was supposed to be another comment to Raymond's answer, but it got too long.)

As already mentioned by Raymond, we have the relationship (using slightly different notation)

$$\Gamma(n,z)= (n-1)! \exp(-z) e_{n-1}(z)$$

where

$$e_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$$

the partial sums of the Maclaurin series for $\exp(z)$, is sometimes called the [exponential sum function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html). Though a general closed form for the roots of $e_n(z)$ is not known, the distribution of the roots of the polynomial $e_n(nz)$ in the complex plane is pretty well studied:

[image: scaled roots of exponential sum functions]

In particular, Gábor Szegő (1924) and Jean Dieudonné (1935) both showed that the roots of the *scaled* exponential sum function $e_n(nz)$ approach the portion of the curve $|z\exp(1-z)|=1$ (now often referred to as the *Szegő curve*) within the unit disk as $n\to\infty$. In [two](http://dx.doi.org/10.1216/rmjm/1181072998) [papers](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0087909), Carpenter, Varga, and Waldvogel study the asymptotics of the zeros of $e_n(nz)$. Other papers of interest include those by [Buckholtz](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2313761), [Newman and Rivlin](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045%2872%2990007-X) ([with correction](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9045%2876%2990061-7)), [Conrey and Ghosh](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322757), [Pritsker and Varga](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-97-01889-8), [Walker](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3647884), and [Zemyan](http://www.jstor.org/stable/30037629). (These are the ones I've read; I'm sure there are other nice papers I've missed.)

Comment: Thanks for the interesting links and nice illustration! I'll just add that the second paper of Varga and Carpenter 'Asymptotics for the zeros of the partial sums of e^z. II' (and many others on the same subject and the related 'partial sums of $\cos(z)\ $ and $\sin(z)\ $') are available at [Varga's homepage](http://www.math.kent.edu/~varga/pub.html). Cheers,

Comment: Very nice, Thanks so much for the graph and references.

Comment: [This](https://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec/2001/MP/sujets/math1.pdf) may also be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

With the usual definition we have :
$$\Gamma(n,x)=\int_x^{\infty} t^{n-1} e^{-t} dt$$

After repeatedly using integration by parts we may get [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Special_values) :
$$\Gamma(n,x)= (n-1)! e^{-x} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
so that you are asking for the zeros of the polynomials : 
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Let's search the first solutions :

$
\begin{array} {rcc}
n & P_n(x) & \mathrm{zeros} \\
\hline \\
1 & 1 & \emptyset \\
2 & 1+x & \{-1\} \\
3 & 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} & \{-1-i,-1+i\} \\
4 & 1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!} & \{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}-\frac1{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{2}-1}}-1,..,.. \} \\
\end{array}
$

I'll stop here because the algebraic expressions of the zeros are becoming rather long and complicated... (search others with [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%5B4,x%5D=0))
Or did you hope something simpler?

Comment: MathWorld refers to these polynomials as [exponential sum functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialSumFunction.html), $e_n(x)$.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks for the link!