# Inequality involving incomplete gamma function

Tags: inequality, special-functions, integral-inequality

When trying to answer this question: [Find minimum $n$ such that $1+z+\frac{z^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{z^n}{n!}=0$ has no answer inside the circle of radius $100$ centered at the origin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543904/find-minimum-n-such-that-1z-fracz22-cdots-fracznn-0-has-no-a/1010197#1010197)

I ended up in what seems to be a dead end, and I'd really like to see it finished. The problem is to find for which $n$, the following inequality holds:
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{100} x^n e^{-x}dx < e^{-200},
$$
and it would be even better if there was some way to solve the general inequality,
$$
\frac{1}{n!}\int_0^{r} x^n e^{-x}dx < e^{-2r}.
$$

Comment: FWIW, you may want to check out the inequalit 1.2 http://campus.mst.edu/adsa/contents/v8n2p8.pdf