# Polynomial W is defined by equation prove that $W(z) \neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Polynomial $W(z) \in \mathbb{C}$ is defined by equation $$
>  W(z)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{2019} \frac{z^{k}}{k !} $$ prove that if  $z \in
>  \mathbb{C}$ and $|z|<10,$ then $W(z) \neq 0$

I need help and some hint. Can you take me some of first step to solution?

Comment: Estimate $e^z - W(z)$

Comment: Per the answer in [zeros of the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^{n} z^k/k!$, inside balls](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/131524/115115), all roots of $p_n(z)$ are inside $\frac{n}{e^2}<|z|<n$, so that there are no roots inside a disk with radius $273$. To show this for the much smaller radius $10$ should be downright trivial. See also the animation of the scaled roots converging to the Szegő curve in [Roots of incomplete gamma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109605/115115) in still diagrams in [properties of roots of the incomplete exponential](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/535720/115115).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course $e^z$ does not vanish over $|z|<10$, so if we manage to prove that $|W(z)-e^z|<e^{-10}$ over $|z|<10$ we are done. $W(z)-e^z$ is an entire function, so by the maximum modulus principle we only need to check its values over $|z|=10$. In such a case

$$ \left|e^z-W(z)\right| = \left|\sum_{k\geq 2020}\frac{z^{k}}{k!}\right|=10^{2020}\left|\sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{z^h}{(2020+h)!}\right|\leq\frac{10^{2020}}{2020!}\sum_{h\geq 0}\frac{10^h}{2020^h}=\frac{10^{2020}}{2020!\left(1-\frac{1}{202}\right)} $$
so it is enough to prove
$$ 10^{2020} e^{10} < 2020!\frac{201}{202}. $$
Since $ 2020!> 2020^{2020} e^{-2020} $ it is enough to prove
$$ 201\cdot 202^{2019} > e^{2030} $$
or
$$ 2019 \log(202)+\log(201) > 2030, $$
which is blatantly true.

Comment: Why if prove that $W(z) - e^{z} < e^{-10}$ over $|z|< 10$ we are done?

Comment: @Blabla: because over the given region $|e^z|=e^{\text{Re}(z)}>e^{-10}$.