# Prove $p_{4}(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} > 0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Here is part of an incomplete proof that I made. First let me establish that, $p_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}=\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3 \ldots$

**Lemma 1:** $p_2(x)$ is always greater than $0$.
**Proof:**
$p_2'(x) = 1 + x$ meaning $p_2$'s one and only stationary point occurs at $x = -1$. $p_2(-1) = \frac{1}{2}$. But $p_2''(x)=1$, meaning that this stationary point is a global minimum. Therefore $p_2(x) \geq \frac{1}{2}\ \forall\  x \in \mathbb{R}$. Lemma proven

**Lemma 2:**
$p_3(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!}+ \frac{x^3}{3!}$ has exactly one root.
**Proof:**
$p_3'(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} = p_2(x)$

Therefore $p_3$ is monotonically increasing. It is also differentiable and continuous across $\mathbb{R}$. $p_3(-2)=-\frac{1}{3}$ and $p_3(-1)=\frac{1}{3}$. And so by the intermediate value theorem, there exists a zero for $p_3$ between $-2$ and $-1$. This must be the only zero, since $p_3$ is monotonically increasing. Lemma proven.

**Original Proof:**
$p_4'(x) = p_3(x)$ and $p_4''(x)=p_2(x)$. And so it is known that there is exactly one stationary point because of *Lemma 1* and that this stationary point must be a global minimum from the *Lemma 2*.

This global minimum will occur at $p_3(x) = 0$, which is beteween $-2$ and $-1$ as shown in Lemma 2. Incomplete. All that's needed is to show that the minimum in this interval is greater than 0.

Comment: You can easily just brute force this. For $x\geq 0$ the claim is obviously true. 

Let $x=-a$ with $a\in]0,1[$. Then we have $1+x > 0$. Furthermore, we have $\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} > \frac{x^2}{3!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} = \frac{a^2 - a^3}{3!} > \frac{a^2 - a^2}{3!} =0$. Trivially, $\frac{x^4}{4!}>0$ and so the whole sum $p_4(x)>0$.

Notice also that $p_4(-1) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{24} > 0$. I leave the final case, of $x=-a$ with $a\in]1,\infty[$ to you.

Comment: Related: [Number of real roots of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{x^{k}}{k!}=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391054/number-of-real-roots-of-sum-k-0n-fracxkk-0). I do not consider that question to be a suitable duplicate target because it is wider in scope (arbitrary $n$) but also more restricted (no induction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've established that $\ p_4\ $ has a  global minimum $\ x_\min\ $, say, which must satisfy $\ p_3\big(x_\min\big)=0\ $ and $\ -2<x_\min<-1\ $.  But $\ p_4(x)=p_3(x)+\frac{x^4}{4!}\ $.  What can you say about the sign of $\ \frac{x^4}{4!}\ $ over the interval $\ -2<x<-1\ $?

Comment: This is the nicer answer, because it generalizes. But it is even easier: $p_4(x)=\frac{x^4}{24}+p_4’(x).$ So where $p_4’(x_0)=0,$ $p_4(x_0)>0,$ unless $x_0=0.$

Answer (score 6):

An alternate approach.

Multiply by $24$ then get:

$$\begin{align}  x^4+4x^3+12x^2+24x+24&=(x+1)^4+6x^2+20x+23\\&=(x+1)^4+6(x+5/3)^2+19/3
\end{align} $$

This doesn’t generalize to $p_{2n}$ easily, though.

(There is a theorem which says a real polynomial is non-negative if and only if it can be written as a sum of squares of real polynomials, I believe.)

Comment: ah, beat me by a minute! I had $\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^2}{2}+x+1 = \frac{1}{24} \left(x^2+2
   x\right)^2+\frac{1}{3} \left(x+\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

If some calculus is allowed, then for $\,x \gt 0\,$:

$$
p_4(-x) =  1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2!} - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} \,\gt\, \sum_{k \ge 0} \,(-1)^k\,\frac{x^k}{k!} \,=\, e^{-x} \,\gt\, 0
$$

This shows that $\,p_4(x)\,$ is positive on $\mathbb R^-$, and quite obviously it is positive on $\mathbb R^+$ as well. More generally, the same argument works to prove that $\,p_{2n}(x) \gt 0\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ As pointed out in [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)' comment, the first inequality is not immmediately obvious, because the $e^{-x}$ series is alternating for $x \gt 0$, but the terms do not decrease in magnitude for small $n$, so the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test#Alternating_series_test) cannot be applied directly.

To show that the inequality does in fact hold, it is enough to use the [Lagrange form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder) of the remainder $\,e^{-x} = p_4(-x) + \frac{(-1)^5\,e^{- t}}{5!} \,x^5\,$ for some $\,t \in (0, x)\,$, then the conclusion follows since the last term is negative. The same argument works for even-power partial sums in general:

$$
p_{2n}(-x) =  \sum_{k = 0}^{2n} \,(-1)^k\,\frac{x^k}{k!} \,=\, e^{-x} \,-\, \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}\,e^{-t}}{(2n+1)!}\,x^{2n+1}  \,\gt\, e^{-x} \,\gt\, 0
$$

Comment: That inequality is not clearly true. $$-\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}+\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}=(x-2n)\frac{x^{2n-1}}{(2n!)}.$$ So some of the additional pairs of terms are positive and negative.

Comment: Yeah, I got the fact backward. It is not clearly true or all $x>0$ because some of the pairs can be positive. It might be true, but it s a big hand-wave to say it is true without an argument.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for raising the point, I edited the question to cover that part.