# Find all real solutions to the following equation.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find all real solutions of:

$1$ + $x$ + $\dfrac{x^2}{2!}$ + $\dfrac{x^3}{3!}$ +...+ $\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ = $0$

This is math club question I haven't made much headway on.

Comment: @JohnMa Of course, I had complex roots in mind, it's much easier with real roots :)

Comment: is this really a duplicate it asks about the exact solutions, not about the existence of them.

Comment: @tired : In the duplicate it shows there is no solution. (for $n$ even)

Comment: The distinction seems moot if there are none. @tired

Comment: ok i didn't read the answer properly, sry

Comment: For the genereal question about the root location see the nice graphic in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109605/115115, "Gábor Szegő (1924) and Jean Dieudonné (1935) both showed that the roots of the scaled exponential sum function $e_n(nz)$ approach the portion of the curve $|z·exp(1−z)|=1$ …  within the unit disk."

Comment: Thanks @JohnMa this was what I was looking for; I tried searching for similar questions before I posted, but I didn't find any.

Comment: I think that's it's extremely hard to search for duplicate here. @T.Jones Sometimes I can't even find my own answer.....

Comment: [Here](https://www.concours-centrale-supelec.fr/CentraleSupelec/2001/MP/sujets/math1.pdf) is something about the complex roots, in french ([Centrale-Supelec](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concours_Centrale-Sup%C3%A9lec) 2001 MP Math-1).