# Roots of the Taylor approximation of the exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, plane-curves

While answering another question, I looked at the roots of the $n^{th}$ degree Taylor approximation of the exponential.

$$e^x\approx E_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$

Apparently, these root are aligned on a parabola-like smooth curve depending on $n$.

[image]

How would you address the problem of finding the equation of this curve, ignoring the exact positions of the roots along it ?

Comment: A neat [answer by JM and some references](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109360).

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: splendid !

Comment: Glad you liked it! Cheers,

Comment: @RaymondManzoni: now, as these roots are the same as those of the  incomplete Gamma $\Gamma(n+1,z)$, we even have a way to study a non-integer number of roots :)