# What is the area bounded by the Szegő Curve?

Tags: exponential-function

I was reading about the zeros of the truncated exponential series and learned about the [Szegő Curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109360/roots-of-the-incomplete-gamma-function/109605#109605). Naturally, I wanted to know the area bounded by the curve.

I read the equation of the curve to be: $$e^{(1-x)}\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = 1$$ and [calculated the area using Wolfram Alpha to be about $.731445$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%20*%20int%20((1%2F(e%5E(1-x)))%5E2%20-%20x%5E2)%5E1%2F2%20dx%20from%20-.27846%20to%201) Is a nice closed form known?

Comment: Your leftmost limit is $-W(e^{-1})$; I'm not sure if there's a closed form for the area, and *Mathematica* seems to not be able to find one.

Comment: In polar coordinates the curve is $re^{1-r\cos\theta}=1$. I wonder if that helps? Probably not.

Comment: The corresponding integral in @Rahul's formulation is $$\int_0^{\pi }\sec^2(\theta)W\left(-\frac{\cos(\theta )}{e}\right)^2 \,\mathrm d\theta$$; not very tractable either.