# Do the roots of $1+x/1!+x^2/2!+\cdots+x^{2n+1}/{(2n+1)!}$ decrease to $-\infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Do the roots of $$P_{2n+1}(x)=1+\frac x{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$ decrease to $-\infty$?

Can we show this? Indeed, $P_{2n+1}(0)=1$, $P_{2n+1}(-(2n+1))<0$. And $P_{2n+1}'(x)=P_{2n}(x)>0$. So $P_{2n+1}$ has only one root $x_n$. Can we show that $x_n\to-\infty$?

Comment: I don't think so: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%2F2%2Bx%5E3%2F3!%2Bx%5E4%2F4!%2Bx%5E5%2F5!%2Bx%5E6%2F6!%2Bx%5E7%2F7!%2Bx%5E8%2F8!%2Bx%5E9%2F9!%2Bx%5E10%2F10!%2Bx%5E11%2F11!%3D0

Comment: @YvesDaoust What is the root of $P_{11}$ supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: @Arthur: that some roots even have a positive real part.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Who said anything about complex numbers?

Comment: @Arthur: who said the opposite ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean, you can probably find lots of questions here which do not _explicitly_ mention that they restrict themselves to the real numbers. There are many small pieces of evidence, mostly using the variable name $x$, and refering to $<$ and $-\infty$. Those all pull toward real numbers. I see nothing pointing towards complex numbers.

Comment: @Arthur: I was mislead by the title.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right. The s in "roots". I'll give you that.

Comment: From the answer in [Roots of the incomplete gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/109360/115115): "Gábor Szegő (1924) and Jean Dieudonné (1935) both showed that the roots of the scaled exponential sum function $e_n(nz)$ approach the portion of the curve $|z\exp(1−z)|=1$ (now often referred to as the Szegő curve) within the unit disk as $n→∞$." This implies that the negative root $\approx -nW(e^{-1})$ (using Lambert-W) is pushed towards $-∞$ at constant speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using, for instance, the [Weierstrass $M$-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), we see that your sequence converges uniformly to $e^x$ on any bounded domain. In other words, for any $X< 0$, there is an $N\in \Bbb N$ such that $$|P_{2n+1}(x) - e^x|<\frac{1}{2}e^X \leq \frac12e^x$$ for any $n> N, x\in [X, -X]$. By the triangle inequality, this implies that $P_{2n+1}$ doesn't have any roots on $[X, -X]$ for such $n$. So yes, $x_n\to -\infty$, as for any finite bound we can pick an $N$ which forces $x_n$ to be below that bound whenever $n>N$.

---

The Weierstrass $M$-test is a very fancy name for a quite simple idea. Basically, say you have a collection of functions $f_n$ for $n\in \Bbb N$ on some domain, and on that domain the absolute value $|f_n|$ of each of those functions is bounded by some number $M_n$. If $\sum M_n < \infty$, then $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly.

In this case, we have $f_n(x) = \frac{x^n}{n!}$, which on $[X, -X]$ is bounded by $M_n = \frac{(-X)^n}{n!}$. Then $\sum M_n = e^{-X}<\infty$, so $\sum f_n$ converges uniformly.

Comment: Isn't it standard to **define** the exponential function $e^x$ as the power series $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ which has radius of convergence $= \infty$ and thus converges uniformly on each compact set?

Comment: @PaulFrost "and thus converges uniformly on each compact set" How would you prove that? Isn't that exactly what I've done here with the $M$-test? Besides, that's just the first half of my argument. The second is actually using that uniform convergence to show the result.

Comment: You are right, it requires a proof. I only wanted to remark that this is a characteristic property of power series.