# Is there a generalized solution to truncated exponential?

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

There's no closed form for the solution to all polynomials, but for certain classes it may be generalizable.

For a table of polynomials
$$\begin{align*}
1 \\
1+t \\
1 + t + \frac{1}{2}t^2 \\
1 + t + \frac{1}{2}t^2 + \frac{1}{6}t^3 \\
...
\end{align*}$$
and so on, is there any kind of generalization for the inverse structure or roots of the partial truncation of the exponential function?

Comment: Are you looking for an expression like this $\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\tfrac{1}{k!}x^k$?

Comment: Yep <insert filler text>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Roots of the incomplete gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109360/roots-of-the-incomplete-gamma-function)

Comment: One of the answers literally just gave up in the middle. So how do I know a closed form isn't possible versus someone saying "I personally don't know the answer" in which case their post isn't relevant?