# Does the norm of the Taylor expansion's partial sum of $e^{ix}$ have a uniform lower bound?

Tags: analysis, polynomials

Since $|e^{ix}|=1$ and $$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(ix)^k}{k!}$$ approximates $e^{ix}$ well near the origin, we can know that $|f_n(x)|\approx 1>0$ for small $x$. My question is that whether there is a constant $C$ such that
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|>C$$
holds for all $n$ (or at least for any $n\in S$, where $S$ has positive density in $\mathbb{N}$)?

My current attempt is to use the fact that
$$\mathrm{Re} [f_n(x)] = \sum_{k=0\\k\  \mathrm{even}}^{n}(-1)^{k/2}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
and
$$\mathrm{Im}[f_n(x)] =  \sum_{k=0\\k\  \mathrm{odd}}^{n}(-1)^{(k-1)/2}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
are coprime in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, which enables us to apply the Bezout's identity to deduce a lower bound for $|f_n(x)|$. However, this method can only prove that $|f_n(x)|>e^{-O(n\log(n))}$, which is not a uniform lower bound.

Are there any tricks to improve this method, or are there any method more analytic rather than using this fact in number theory?

Comment: My guess would be that $|f_n(x)|$ does *not* have a uniform positive lower bound. The asymptotic location of the zeros of $e_n(z)=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{z^k}{k!}$ are known (see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109605/42969), and that indicates that many $e_n$ have zeros on or close to the imaginary axis.

Comment: Can you add your proof of $|f_n(x)|>e^{-O(n\log(n))}$ to the question?